# Is there a way to directly download an iOS app (without using the app store)

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, app-store

I would like to have users be directed to a link which will immediately start downloading an app on an iOS device.  I know you can register for Enterprise application or do limited ad-hoc distribution, but this is not the case here.  The app I would like to link to is already on the app store.  I would like to know if users can download the app directly without going through the app store.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As mentioned above, you cannot provide a direct link to the application. There are ways of circumventing the app store, such as ad-hoc distribution and ADC's enterprise program. However, neither of these would provide the convenience you seek as potential users would have to install certificates generated by you before installing your application. Your best option would be to use the app store or possibly a web app.As David V mentioned, you can provide a direct link to your app in the app store!

Good luck,

-Alex

Answer (score 2):

They will need to go through the App Store. You can provide them a link to your app in the App Store though.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, even in jailbroken devices,  you need to use a store. Apple seems not to have a auto-installing url scheme implemented. 
Would be nice, though.

Answer (score 0):

No.  This is not possible on stock OS iOS devices

Answer (score -1):

You can do that if your app is based on Safari (web app) instead of native (iOS).